# Assign array in Linked List node

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, struct

I recently got into programming and I just learned about **Linked Lists**. I know how to assign individual elements like `char` or `int` in a node in a Linked List.

I was trying to assign a `char` **array** in a single node, and then for each node print the elements of the array.

Here is the part of my code in which I have tried to do the above:

```
node* ReadList() {
  node *head = NULL, *n, *m;
  char data[20], c;
  bool lmfao = false;
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
    c = getchar();
    if (c == ' ') break;
    data[i] = c;
  }

  n = new node;
  n->next = NULL;
  n->info = data[];
  head = n;

  while (!lmfao) {

   for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
     c = getchar();
     if (c == ' ') break;
     if (c == EOF) lmfao = true;
     data[i] = c;
   }

   if (!lmfao) {
     m = new node;
     n->next = m;
     m->info = data[];
     m->next = NULL;
     n = m;

   }

   if (lmfao) {
     m = new node;
     n->next = m;
     m->info = data[];
     m->next = NULL;
   }
  }

  return head;
}
```

For the sake of this example lets say that the series of letters is not longer than 20 characters.

When I try to compile this I get the error message:

```
test.cpp:23:18: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
test.cpp:38:21: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
test.cpp:47:21: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
```

I have tried to use `data` instead of `data[]` but then i get this:

```
test.cpp:36:16: error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
```

which I totally understand, because I tried to convert a pointer to a `char` value.

**Either way I have no clue as to what I can do to assign the
entire array in a single node.**

Assigning a single element in each node would not work for what I'm trying to do.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `n->info = data[];`, etc is not right. What type is `info`? According the error, it appears to be a `char`. It should be a `char *` and you need to allocate it with `new`, then copy the data. Or, preferably, use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes `data[]` is `char` but i need it to stay like that because im trying to assign a word in each node, so `char *` would not work unless im missing something. As i said im new to programming so i don't really know what `std::vector` or `std::array` is. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: When you say "word" I assume you mean a "string". A "string" _is_ an array of `char` with a special null char at the end.